# Detect when <iframe> parent element changes from hidden to shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, reload, detect

How can I detect when an iframe is shown from hidden element ?

**HTML :**

```
<div style="display:none">
 <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

So when I show the `<div>` by jQuery via `$('div').show();`, 
How can I **detect** and **reload** this iframe ?

**PS :** Detection should happen inside an iframe file.

**NOT :** `$('div').show(function(){//do something});` or this ? (NOW I NOT SURE)

Comment: If you want to use the callback function, you should add `duration`.

Comment: @undefined Expand pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').show("slow",function(){
  var iframe = $(this).find("iframe");
   iframe.attr('src', "SOME_URL");
});
```

Comment: Let me some min for testing :D Thanks anyway